Lifting of projective representation
Let $G$ be a finite group and $\sigma: G \to PGL(V)$ be a projective representation. Define the fixed-point subspase $$ End(V)^G = \{ X \in End(V) \mid \sigma_g(X) = X \ \ \forall g \in G \} $$ of $End(V)$.
We know that $End(V)^G \ne End_G(V)$ unless $\sigma$ is lifted to $G \to GL(V)$. However, $\sigma$ can be lifted to $\tilde{G} \to GL(V)$, where $\tilde{G}$ is a central extension of $G$. What can we say about $End_{\tilde{G}}(V)$? Is there any relation like $End_{\tilde{G}}(V)=End(V)^G$ or $End_{\tilde{G}}(V) \subset End(V)^G$?

They are equal by definition, just check it (the action of $\widetilde{G}$ by conjugation on $\text{End}(V)$ by definition restricts to the original projective representation of $G$).

Does it mean for every projective representation $\sigma: G \to PGL(V)$ there exists a linear representation $\rho: \tilde{G} \to GL(V)$ such that  $\sigma_g(X)=\rho_g^{-1}X\rho_g$ for each $g \in G$ and $X \in End(V)$?

That is the definition of what it means for $\sigma$ to lift to $\rho$.
